# javascript - variable scope

Tags: javascript, scope

This is a silly question, but I'm trying to use the contents from `var form_data` outside the ajax scope. How would I go about doing this? form_data only seems to exist inside the ajax function rather than outside even after declaring the variable outside of the ajax scope. I thought variables bubbled up until it finds where it was declared when `var` isn't defined.

To clarify my question, how do I use the results from the server outside the success function? I don't want to limit myself to doing everything inside the ajax success callback.

```
$(function () {

    var form_data; 

    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'print_form.php',
        data: {
            //data sent to server
        },
        success: function (response) {
            form_data = JSON.parse(response);
            console.log(form_data);            //object is printed out as expected
        },

        error: function () {
            alert('AJAX failed for print_form');
        }
    });

    console.log(form_data);                    //undefined

});
```

Comment: form_data only gets assigned in the success function. Since its asynchronous, the `console.log` outside of the ajax function is still being called while the ajax request is happening

Comment: Start using `done()` .. See jQuery docs http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As AJAX stands for Asynchronous Javascript and Xml, so your code doesn't get blocked for an ajax operation being executed as it's asynchronous. In your case what happen is that when you are getting data through ajax your javascript doesn't stop continuing of execution and wait for the request to get success. Rather then that, while you are getting the data the rest of the code still gets executed. And that's why before you get the from the server through ajax request the `form_data` already gets printed outside of the ajax request scope.

***Let's test it :***

Try initializing `form_data` with any value. You'll find that now you won't get undefined outside the ajax where you printed the value. Rather you'll get the value you initialized the variable with.

Comment: does this mean I'm forced to do everything I need to do with the response from AJAX within the success callback?

Comment: either you do it inside `.success` or you can get your rest of the code get executed when your are done with the response using `.done`

Comment: basically if you want to use a variable somewhere after you get it initialized by the response of server it's obvious to wait till you get the data. And as you are showing your data before it's getting response from the service you are getting it `undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

> An alternative construct to the success callback option, the .done()
>   method replaces the deprecated jqXHR.success() method. Refer to
>   deferred.done() for implementation details.
>   source: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Build your code as given in the docs:

I am having success with this setup that isolates the Ajax call.

```
function sendAjax(xhrdata) {


       return $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'print_form.php',
         data: xhrdata
        }).promise();

}

sendAjax(data).done(function(response) {
     form_data = JSON.parse(response);
     console.log(form_data); 
}
```